# By sending HTTP POST request to another site, how to receive the result of the request?

Tags: web, http-post

By sending HTTP POST request to another site, a value is generated and printed out. How to obtain the value?

For examole, http://www.twiddla.com/new.aspx accepts HTTP POST requests from my website containing my Twiddla username. Like I've written this code on my site,

```
<form action="http://www.twiddla.com/new.aspx" method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Create Meeting">
```

By submitting the form, the page is redirected to twiddla.com/new.aspx and in that page, a numeric ID is printed out. How can my website obtain the ID and save it in database?

Comment: I found the answer. I create a PHP caller function. stream_context_create and stream_get_contents are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can do one of this:

- use a callback (has to be provided by the other website)
- use php or any other language to connect to the service.

Comment: Thank you wbiller, I choose the second option